# JavaFX Alert Box Not Closing on 1st Click

Tags: javafx, alert

I know this is probably an easy error to fix but I am not finding it.  When the alert box comes up and you click on it takes 2 clicks to close it

```
private Product getProductById(int id) {
    ObservableList<Product> allProducts = Inventory.getAllProducts();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < allProducts.size(); i++) {
        Product inv = allProducts.get(i);
        
        if(inv.getId() == id) {
            return inv;
        } else {
              Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
              alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
              alert.setHeaderText("Item Not Found");
              alert.setContentText("The item you are searching for is not in the list!");

              alert.show();
              break;           
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `showAndWait` instead of `show`

Comment: Thanks, just tried that but its actually loading a 2nd window after the 1st one closes.

Comment: @MicheleAnnRiedel ok that means that whole bit of code is running twice, so the problem isn’t with the alert. Try using the debugger an step through the code to where it is being called.

Comment: Found it thank you!  It was because I was calling the ObservableList in two areas and had the alert listed both times.

Comment: @MicheleAnnRiedel that's why you should __always__ provide a [mcve] when asking for debugging help (== _x-y isn't working as expected_ :)